# DatePicker for UITextfield,should I use NSDatePicker?

Tags: iphone, datepicker, uitextfield

I have a UITextfield "Birthday" and right now after clicking on the text field I have a keyboard and I would like to change it to a datepicker.

Is there anyone who can help step by step with this?what should I add to my code and what changes do I need to make.

Here is what I have for my UITextField "Birthady":

```
field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self.appDel.styleManager decorateTextField:field];
field.placeholder = @"Birthday";
[container addSubview:field];
self.registrationFormBirthday = field;
self.registrationFormBirthday.delegate = self;
```

Based on Jonathan answer this is what I have right now:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
    if textField == XtextLabel
    {
    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] ;
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init] ;
    [comps setYear:-0];
    NSDate *maximumDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];
    [comps setYear:-90];
    NSDate *minimumDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps toDate:currentDate options:0];
    [datePicker setMaximumDate:maximumDate];
    [datePicker setMinimumDate:minimumDate];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    textField.inputView = datePicker;
    }
    }
```

How Can I show the selected date on in the XtextLabel and exit datePicker?

Comment: Have a look at the inputview of the UITextfield, you can set this to a UIDatePicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like...

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[[UIDatePicker alloc] init]];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:)      forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
textField.inputView = datePicker;    


- (IBAction)datePickerValueChanged:(id)sender {

   NSDate *pickerDate = [sender date]; //Do something with the date
}
```

Comment: THANKS,why am I getting this error after I'm clicking on a year || month || day?   -[NRLoginViewController datePickerValueChanged]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: So whats happening here is that with the addTarget method, we are telling the datePicker control to call a function whenever the date is changed. In this case the function is datePickerValueChanged. You can remove that line if you don't want to anything more with the date value at that point.

Comment: I've added the function to the answer for you to have an idea.

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan, how can I limit the year on this?

Comment: You can set minimumDate and maximumDate on UIDatePicker.

Comment: yesss I set minimumDate and maximumDate,One more question how can I show the selected date on the UITextField and get out of DatePicker?